# Send a signal/event to an independent process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

So I have a completely independent process, with a known PID.

I want to send it some kind of interrupt from another unrelated process that will cause it to 'gracefully' exit.

In **linux** it would look something like this :

first_script:

```
def signal_handler(signum, stack):
    print("SIGNAL RECIEVED")
    sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handle_signal)
while True:
    print("Im working")
```

Second script:

```
known_pid = input("Enter pid")
os.kill(int(known_pid), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Since, Windows doesn't support signaling in this way, it obviously won't work but I couldn't find any other simple solution (After quite extensive research).

Comment: Does the process have a window that can be sent `WM_CLOSE`? Most GUI apps will exit gracefully (including asking to save files) if the main window is closed. This is what taskkill.exe does by default without the /F option. This can also be used for a console process if it's the effective owner of the console window (usually if it allocated the console). When the console window is closed, all applications attached to it (not just the owner) have no more than 5 seconds to handle the control event and exit gracefully before getting terminated.

Comment: @eryksun It isnt a windows application(no GUI), and it isnt the owner of the console (otherwise I could use some varation of ctrl+c signals).

Comment: Even if it were a console app, sending Ctrl+C is not simple in Windows. You have to be attached to the console (e.g. `AttachConsole`, `FreeConsole`).  `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` works only with process groups, not arbitrary process IDs. If you know the group ID (i.e. the PID of the lead process), then you probably created the process with `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, which disables Ctrl+C by default, so you have to use Ctrl+Break instead. Otherwise without a known group, you have to send to group 0 (all attached processes) and ignore the event in your own process.

Comment: If it has no window or console, your last hope is that it's hosting a service (or services) that you can stop. Otherwise there's no standard way to signal a process. Windows has capabilities for this such as asynchronous procedure calls (APCs), named pipes, mailslots, events, and semaphores, but they're not a generic mechanism. An application has to be designed with a documented way to receive the signal.

Comment: @Rohi does any of the answers have what you need? If not, what is missing? If you found a solution by yourself, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Windows API as provided by [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) or hack it with a socket.

The socket solution is quick and dirty:

```
# waiting process

import socket
import select
import time

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('localhost', 1337))
server.listen(5)

# this select() call returns ([server], [], [])
# if server is readable, else ([], [], []), and waits 0 seconds
while not select.select([server], [], [], 0)[0]:
    print('working')
    time.sleep(0.5)


# parent process

import socket    
socket.create_connection(('localhost', 1337))
```

The windows solution is longer but more accurately represents the problem:

```
# waiting process

import time
import win32event

# open an existing event by name with the required access
# (didn't work for me with EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, got "Access denied" error)
event = win32event.OpenEvent(win32event.EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "MY_NAME")

# Wait 0 seconds on the event. If event has been set, WAIT_OBJECT_0 is returned
while win32event.WaitForSingleObject(event, 0) != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    print('working')
    time.sleep(0.5)


# parent process
# note that it should be run first

import win32event
import time

# create event by name
event = win32event.CreateEvent(
    None,       # not inherited by child processes
    False,      # auto-reset the event after it is set
    False,      # created unset
    "MY_NAME",  # event name
)
time.sleep(5)  # wait for waiting process to start
win32event.SetEvent(event)
```

This is only a minimal POC. It is recommended that you read about [event objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/event-objects) to find the exact solution that suits you.

Comment: The event-based approach is the right one (with sockets you can have painful timeouts). You can call `CreateEvent` with the same parameters on both sides (so you don't have to run one process before the other), just make sure you handle the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` error code. In this case `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE` should be ok instead of `EVENT_ALL_ACCESS`

Comment: Hey, this looks like it could solve my problem. Ill have a thorough look at it tomrrow.

Comment: You dont actually have to open the event before the proccess check it, you can try catch on the proccess, making this a really good solution.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why I might be getting `pywintypes.error: (2, 'OpenEvent', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')` when I try to open a named event like you've shown here?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't create the event before trying to open it

Answer (score 1):

How about consider using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil), I think it is quite suitable for your case.

As stated in [document](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#recipes), following code can do what you want. Though you may not need the part of `find_procs_by_name`.

```
import os
import signal
import psutil

def find_procs_by_name(name):
    "Return a list of processes matching 'name'."
    ls = []
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=["name", "exe", "cmdline"]):
        if name == p.info['name'] or \
                p.info['exe'] and os.path.basename(p.info['exe']) == name or \
                p.info['cmdline'] and p.info['cmdline'][0] == name:
            ls.append(p)
    return ls

def kill_proc_tree(pid, sig=signal.SIGTERM, include_parent=True,
                   timeout=None, on_terminate=None):
    """Kill a process tree (including grandchildren) with signal
    "sig" and return a (gone, still_alive) tuple.
    "on_terminate", if specified, is a callabck function which is
    called as soon as a child terminates.
    """
    if pid == os.getpid():
        raise RuntimeError("I refuse to kill myself")
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    if include_parent:
        children.append(parent)
    for p in children:
        p.send_signal(sig)
    gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(children, timeout=timeout,
                                    callback=on_terminate)
    return (gone, alive)

pid = find_procs_by_name('POWERPNT.EXE')[0].pid
print(find_procs_by_name('POWERPNT.EXE')[0].pid)
kill_proc_tree(pid)
```